# download file in django 1.7

Tags: python-3.4, django-1.7

I need to provide a button, once the user click on it It will download a PDF file or Image.

I have been tried so many ways out there. non of them works.
and I couldn't find any tutorial for this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll copypaste a working code from my own question (Django 1.7, Python 3.4):
[Django 1.7: serve a pdf -file (UnicodeDecodeError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190318/django-1-7-serve-a-pdf-file-unicodedecodeerror)

from views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def download(request, file_name):
    file = open('path/to/file/{}'.format(file_name), 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename={}".format(file_name)
    return response
```

Comment: can you show me the related code in settins.py please?

Comment: I will get PermissionError

Comment: My settings.py isn't anything special - I just added my app to the list of apps. If you get PermissionError, the first thing I'd look in is your file directory (I created a temp directory with +777 -access, which is probably not a good idea as such - at least you should remove the executable -rights).

Are you running the server on your own computer or a remote hosting service? Also, just stating "PermissionError" isn't informative enough.